# Can an id be added to the parent of an iframe depending on the child page?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have taken over a site where a button launches a modal window. Inside that modal an iFrame opens a page based on the button that has been clicked. I'm being tasked with assigning an id to the iFrame so the child page can be tracked. All of the files are hosted on the same server.

Since the page is loading dynamically in a modal window, there is no way to track how often a particular button has been clicked. Tracking in this case is used to determine if the button is named properly, or in a good location for the user.

I've tried writing a couple of different script to the child page:

```
 if ( window.location !== window.parent.location ) {
    console.log("look what I found!");
    $("iframe").attr("src", $(this).attr("id","confirmbet"));
  }
```

and

```
//test if the window opens in an iframe
parent.$("iframe").each(function(iel, el) {
  if(el.contentWindow === window) console.log("iframe") ;
});
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementsByTagName("iframe").setAttribute("id","confirmbet")
}
```

I'm trying to get the iframe on the parent page to include an id, i.e.

````html
<iframe src="examplepage.html" **id="idofchildpage"**>```
````

Comment: You want to assign an id to an iframe when a button is clicked?

Comment: The approach `parent.$("iframe").each` should work after checking if parent exists. What happened with that one? Not sure how adding an id will help with tracking though

Comment: Do you have to do this from the child page? I mean, you could just assign the id when creating the iframe in the first place...

Comment: @HereticMonkey it doesn't have to be from the child, but since multiple iframes can be opened in the same modal I though it might be easiest to use the child to assign the id.

Comment: @charlietfl that approach wrote the the console log but the function did nothing.

Comment: Well if it wrote to console it means you found a match ..no?

Comment: @SeanT yes, that's what I'm trying to accomplish. The iframes are different depending on which button is clicked

Comment: @charlietfl yes, it wrote to the console, but it does not add an id to the iframe.

Comment: Should be a simple `el.id ='someValue` within that conditional

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @charlietfl, I came up with:

```
parent.$("iframe").each(function(iel, el) {
    if(el.contentWindow === window) el.id ="confirmbet" ;
 });
```

This works great for what I need to accomplish.